# Strange CultureNotFoundException in a ASP.NET Core Api Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

This is extracted from the Azure App Service eventlog. I think it is related to some Localizated Int.Parse(string, CultureInfo) I need to use because I have to deal with several distinct cultures.
¿Any answer to fix this problem?

```
EventId: 2
RequestId: 8004d77f-0000-f100-b63f-84710c7967bb
RequestPath: /AqApiMain
SpanId: 950dbd1722568446
TraceId: ac982bf4d892904e93be1e94cd04e2e6
ParentId: 0000000000000000

Connection ID "17365880164751562619", Request ID "8004d77f-0000-f100-b63f-84710c7967bb": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.

Exception: 
System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported. (Parameter 'name')
en_US is an invalid culture identifier.
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name, Boolean useUserOverride)
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(String name)
   at AqProjectHopkinsAgain.Services.AqMainService..ctor(BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient) in C:\Users\verbo\source\repos\AqProjectHopkinsAgain2\Services\AqMainService.cs:line 47
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite singletonCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass1_0.&lt;RealizeService&gt;b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngine.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method(Closure , IServiceProvider , Object[] )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerActivatorProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4_0.&lt;CreateActivator&gt;b__0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass5_0.&lt;CreateControllerFactory&gt;g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&amp; next, Scope&amp; scope, Object&amp; state, Boolean&amp; isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.&lt;InvokeFilterPipelineAsync&gt;g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.&lt;InvokeAsync&gt;g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.&lt;Invoke&gt;g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.Core.IISHttpContextOfT`1.ProcessRequestAsync()
</Data></EventData></Event><Event><System><Provider Name="Visual Studio Remote Debugger"/><EventID>1001</EventID><Level>1</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords>Keywords</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime="2020-09-03T11:14:32Z"/><EventRecordID>1250925329</EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer>RD0050F28109E2</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data>Msvsmon was unable to start a server named '127.0.0.1:52845'. The following error occurred: An instance of the remote debugger is already running on this computer, or another process is already bound to the specified TCP/IP port.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`en_US` should be `en-US`.

Create it like this:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

Comment: Wow, my friend. Thanks a lot. I couldn't see it after so many logs one after the other.